# Add or remove value from lot of input

Tags: jquery

How to give distinct action for the [+] and for the [-] button? Right now the action impact all the inputs.

If the input is empty and if I click in [+] or [-], how can I assume the value  with 0, even if the value = ""?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vyeq0u31/)

```
$input = $('input[type="text"]');

$('.btn').on('click',function(){
     $val = $input.val();
    if ($(this).hasClass('btn-minuse')) {
     $input.val(parseInt($val)-1);
    } else {
    $input.val(parseInt($val)+1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to target the input of the same `input-group` so

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  var $input = $(this).closest('.input-group').find('input');
  var val = +$input.val();
  $input.val(($(this).hasClass('btn-minuse') ? val - 1 : val + 1) || 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="shrink">TICKET</th>
      <th class="shrink">VALUE</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Y00001</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-minuse" type="button">-</button>
          </span>
          <input type="text" name="Y00001" class="form-control text-center" maxlength="3" value="">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">+</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Y00002</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-minuse" type="button">-</button>
          </span>
          <input type="text" name="Y00002" class="form-control text-center" maxlength="3" value="">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">+</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Y07851</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-minuse" type="button">-</button>
          </span>
          <input type="text" name="Y07851" class="form-control text-center" maxlength="3" value="">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">+</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Y71710</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-minuse" type="button">-</button>
          </span>
          <input type="text" name="Y71710" class="form-control text-center" maxlength="3" value="">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">+</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the initial value is not a number. So we can just check if the value is `''` by using `($val.length == 0) ? 0 : $val` and set value to 0 if the value passed is *null*

```
$input = $('input[type="text"]');

$('.btn').on('click',function(){
    $val = $input.val();
    $val = ($val.length == 0) ? 0 : $val;
    if ($(this).hasClass('btn-minuse')) {
        $input.val(parseInt($val)-1);
    else 
        $input.val(parseInt($val)+1);
});
```

Comment: I think a little explanation would make the answer better. thanks

Comment: @dav explanation added.

Answer (score 0):

You need to target each input relative to the button you're clicking on. With your example you're targeting all the inputs at once. Try:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function () {
    $input = $(this).closest('div').find('input');
    $val = $input.val() || 0;
    $input.val($(this).hasClass('btn-minuse') ? parseInt($val, 10) - 1 : parseInt($val, 10) + 1);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vyeq0u31/1/)**